# Cannot Access XAMPP Web Server From External Network

Tags: xampp, webserver, port

I currently have 4 websites running off my home desktop PC using XAMPP. They are running on ports 80, 81, 7733, and 25293.

The first three run fine when accessed from an external network, however the last (25293) won't load. (This site can't be reached. ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED)

I am port forwarding all 4 ports the exact same way. Just as soon as I'm not on my local network, the page stops loading.

[image: port forward]

I attempted to open up the port in my firewall as well however that achieved nothing. What can I do to resolve this?

The error I receive upon visiting the port on an external network:

[image: External Access Error]

Comment: Try external port 25293 internal port 7733. This will show you wheter your ISP might block that port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a common issue because you are using 5 digits port number, you may need port validation.

For example this was known issue for Drupal:
https://www.drupal.org/project/link/issues/182916

Are you running Linux, or Windows server?

Comment: Server is on Windows. Router is Linux I believe. I changed the port to 4 digits (both internal and external and it worked correctly). So if I'm understanding the issue correctly, it's the internal port's problem, not the external?

Comment: It is port validation issue, so prolly might be caused by router validation. Anyway just stay in safe side, and always stick to 4 digits :) . Glad it worked.

Comment: I'll contact the router manufacturers to confirm, but it looks like that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another computer on the same network? If so, can that computer access your webserver? Try, because that must be your first step, then worry about being visible to the outside world.

I just saw this [link](https://irvingduran.com/2013/02/how-to-access-xampp-from-external-address-http-and-mysql/) and [this](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/access-xampp-server-remotely-0168340/) one. Try to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Devices on the same network can access the webserver and all sites. As soon as they disconnect from the network, that one site becomes a problem.

Comment: check if your port is open or not, follow this [link](https://www.grc.com/x/portprobe=25293) using after connecting on the same network as your server.